# jQuery: testing contents of a variable and is this fiddle broke?

Tags: jquery

In this fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/mjmitche/urfXq/44/  there is an array which is graphically represented by three small boxes (red, blue, green). If you click the bigger black box, it's supposed to

First -- randomly choose one element (either RED, BLUE or GREEN) from the array

Second -- assign that randomly chosen color to a variable called "randomlyChosenColor"--*I'm sure I did this part wrong*.

Third --use the function toLowerCase on the id of the randomly chosen color id

So, I'm sure that none of that is working, because I'm a newbie, but just to make sure, how can I

a) test to see what is contained in the variable randomlyChosenColor ?  is there a print_r type function that php has?

b) if there is problems with my program, can you please help me see what needs to change?

---

Why did I assign the return value to a variable and to lower case? 
After the color is randomly chosen and assigned to a variable, the user (in a part not written yet) is going to guess which was randomly chosen, so the variable is put to lower case to compare it to the button the user will click later on

Comment: Tips: (a) The JavaScript runs in the `<head>` (no wrap (head)) and not when the page finished loading (onLoad), so jQuery cannot find the `#button` element. (b) Your code as syntax errors. Click the `jsLint` button and fix the errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've changed your code a bit:

1. now code running at DomReady
2. click handler is modified

Result: http://jsfiddle.net/urfXq/46/

Comment: Thank you very much.   ON your code (as well as mine), when I run jslint, it says there's an array at line 4. Although your code works, is this error important in your opinion? Error:
Problem at line 4 character 24: Use the array literal notation [].
var myArray = new Array();

Comment: That's not a big problem, just use `var myArray = [];`

Answer (score 1):

Just correct your script, Your script should look like:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    var myArray = new Array();
    myArray[0] = "RED";
    myArray[1] = "BLUE";
    myArray[2] = "GREEN";

    //function getRandom to choose a random element from array
    function getRandom(array, getVal) {
        var key = Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length);

        if (getVal) {
            return array[key];
        }

        return key;
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#button').click(function () {
            $('#button').css('background', getRandom(myArray, true).toLowerCase());
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: cool, thanks, someone answered before you so I gave them accepted answer, but i learned from yours too